# Do not submit form in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

I'm doing submit form in laravel but when I click button with `type=submit`, it doesn't work.
Here is my form in View:

```
<form action="{{ url('p/activation/'.$petition->slug)}}" method="POST" role="form" id="activate-user">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        ........
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" form="activate-user">
                Okay, I'm done
            </button>
</form>
```

and here is my Route to access:

```
Route::post('p/activation/{slug}','Frontend\PetitionController@storeActivation')->name('petitions.storeActivation');
```

I do not redirect to another page when I submit.

Comment: Is your form not submit at all or submit but show some error?

Comment: If submit action working fine then check with print_r($_POST); die; at the top of your storeActivation function

Comment: yeahhh, i submited but not show error and it's load current page again :(

Comment: check your form action then by debugging it in your browser.. action="{{ url('p/activation/'.$petition->slug)}}"

Answer (score 0):

Submit all form records into MySQL table using laravel 5 version. Follow the simple code

**Route:**

```
Route::post('user_details_insert','UserController@user_data_insert');
```

**Form:**

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'user_details_insert','method'=>'post','class'=>'form-signup','files'=>true))}}
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label>Enter Name:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"><br>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label>Enter Email:</label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"><br>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label>Enter Password:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd"><br>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label>&nbsp; </label><br/>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit Data</button>
</div>
{{Form::close()}}
```